# How to distribute microservices through nginx?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, nginx, microservices

I am new to microservices architecture and I have three REST services which was in a monothlithic architecture which I converted into three micro services (seperate DB and stuff) which have their own embedded web server (Spring boot fat jar) . Initially I had to serve the API through a reverse proxy so I map all the path (doamin:8080/application01) to something like this.

```
location /application01 {       
    proxy_pass http://username.github.io/project;
    proxy_redirect http://username.github.io http://a.b;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

But now I had to it three times since all my microservices are having three different ports.I am reading about API gateway.But if I implement that wouldn't it be a single point failure.If then what is the diffence between a monothlithic and which i am implementing right now.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're right. It is a single point of failure.
To my understanding the advantage is, that you can scale an API Gateway better than the whole monolith + the API gateway doesn't suffer as much as the monolith from a high amount of traffic. In the API gateway you could use a load balancer, so you can scale your microservices behind this load balancer as much as you want (in combination with a service discovery)

Comment: With "as much as you want" I mean dynamically, based on the current load, still limited by your resources of course ;)

Comment: API Gateway offers other benefits also: https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/optimizing-the-netflix-api-5c9ac715cf19